# Reltool copies files I don't want into release

Tags: erlang, reltool

I have the following `.config` file:

```
{sys, [
    {lib_dirs, ["/Users/dan/learn_you_some_erlang/erlcount"]},
    {rel, "erlcount", "1.0.0", [
            kernel,
            stdlib,
            {ppool, permanent},
            {erlcount, transient}
        ]},
    {boot_rel, "erlcount"},
    {erts, [
        {mod_cond, derived},
        {app_file, strip}]},
    {profile, embedded}
]}.
```

and when I run [`reltool`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/reltool.html), I get a directory `erts-9.1/doc` containing a 400-page book about Erlang (among other things). How do I get rid of this?

I tried adding `{excl_sys_filters, ["^doc"]}` to the `erts` options, but I get an error

```
Illegal option: {excl_sys_filters,[\"^doc\"]}
```